# "In the open sea everything must be recorded in the Log. "

Tags: etymology

Why the book where  the  record of a ship's speed, its progress, and any shipboard events of navigational importance is called Log?

Answer (score 7):

The name is derived from the [chip log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_log), a device used to measure a ship speed. The book was used mainly to keep a record of the ship speed, so it was called the [logbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logbook), then reduced to just log.

Comment: Would it normally be capitalised, as in the question, or not, as in your answer?

Comment: Normally not capitalised.

Comment: It seems difficult to accept that the origin of "ship's log" has nothing to do with Greek "logos" meaning "word" or "account", but everything I can find online attributes the name to the use of the physical log as answered above.